# What can be reason for different Version and Build in Xcode 15.0.1 and on Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store, versioning

I just uploaded an app to Appstore, in Xcode (15.0.1) Archive Organizer it is showing Correct  Versions, but when check on Appstore it is showing different version number.

Any idea what could be the reason?

[image: Uploaded App from Xcode 15.0.1]

[image: Got the Different Build version on Appstore when adding app to Test Flight]

I have gone through few links on SO but found not useful in my case.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693862)

Comment: On the top screenshot you have your version "5.9.0" and the build "5.9.2." App Store shows you the same version ("5.9.0") and build "7." The versions are the same on both screenshots.

Comment: Version  is 5.9.0 and Build is 5.9.2 when uploading but when viewing on Test Flight it shows Build as 7 any idea what could be the reason?